# Is it possible to have a single flexbox item be multiline?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve this exact UI using CSS flexbox:

[image]

My DOM looks like this:

```
<container>
  <item>The</item>
  <item>Quick</item>
  <item>brown fox jumps over the lazy</item>
  <item>dog</item>
</container>
```

Notice that some  items are long enough to be multiline whilst other items are short enough that they should be on the same line.

There's only one way that I know of to achieve this UI, and that's by removing the whitespace between the items:

```
<container>
  <item>The</item><item>Quick</item><item>brown fox jumps over the lazy</item><item>dog</item>
</container>

<style>
container {
  max-width: 150px;
  display: block;
}

item {
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  display: inline;
}

item:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

item:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

item:nth-child(3) {
  background: orange;
}

item:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

This leaves something to be desired on two accounts:

1. Forcing all of the items on a single line makes the DOM hard to read, especially in more complex scenarios.
2. It requires the hack of modifying the line-height to achieve the desired height.

I would love to achieve this exact UI using CSS Flexbox instead but I cannot find a way to get Flexbox to wrap on multiple lines like this. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible with Flexbox alone, but if you add a script you can accomplish that, where the script could wrap each word.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a complex method to accomplish what you asked using flexbox and maintaining the same html structure, well that's not just possible at all. You `can't just break a flex-item to wrap` in different lines. If you want them to wrap, they need to `be a seperate item` in the first place.

I have modified the html to demonstrate how it could still be used to achieve that.

```css
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

item:nth-child(n+1) {
  background: red;
}

item:nth-child(n+2) {
  background: green;
}

item:nth-child(n+3){
  background: yellow;
}
item:nth-child(n+8){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <item>The</item>
  <item>Quick</item>
  <item>brown</item>
  <break></break>
  <item>fox jumps over the </item>
  <break></break>
  <item>lazy</item>
  <item>dog</item>
</container>
```

Comment: I’m afraid this solution isn’t satisfactory since the words “Brown” and “lazy” need to be a part of the same element that says “fox jumps over the.” In real life the content is coming from the database.

Comment: @MartynChamberlin Like I said, you can't just break items using flexbox. It doesnt work that way but I showed how to workaround it if needed and flexbox isn't the ideal thing to use in this case.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for weighing in!